# Boundedness of two sequences

Tags: real-analysis

Let $x_n$ and $y_n$ be two sequences on the natural numbers. Then if $(\lvert x_n\rvert + \lvert y_n\rvert )$ converges then $x_n$ and $y_n$ are bounded.

I cannot seem to understand intuitively or by proof how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: $|x_n|\le |x_n|+|y_n|$ and convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: Thank you! If I understood correctly, since |xn|≤|xn|+|yn| this implies that |xn| is bounded which in turn implies xn is bounded.

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.